# An element of a group with exactly two conjugate elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group that has an element $g$ with exactly two conjugate elements.Prove that $G$ contains a proper non trivial normal subgroup $N$.

Can someone give some help with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Exactly two, including itself?

Comment: i think that the problem asks about two different elements from g

Comment: If it says exactly two conjugate elements then that is exactly what it means. Why would you imagine that this would not include $g$ itself? Every element is conjugate to itself. But as it happens, the conclusion would still hold if $g$ had exactly three conjugates, or even exactly four conjugates, or five even.  The smallest conjugacy class of $A_5$ has size $12$.

Comment: @Derek I see how to prove that (with a permutation representation) but this problem is a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of a conjugacy class is the index of the centralizer of the element, and a subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

Comment: this is true but i also have to prove that the centralizer is non trivial and a proper subgroup of $G$..

Comment: @capo a subgroup of index $2$ has half as many elements as the group. Thus it is proper, and since this can't happen in a group of order $2$ it is also nontrivial.

Comment: O yes..thank you for your help.

Comment: @capo No problem.